# Spring Boot + Hibernate One To One Mapping

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I need an example on CRUD Operations on two tables with one-to-one mapping using

Hibernate.

I want to learn how this is done in Spring Boot.

I already referred [this][1]

link, but it shows only one table.

If anyone has such a link to a website/github, it will be tremendously helpful.

Thanks in advance

**My working code**

/////////////////////////Main App//////////////////////////////

```
package com;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWeb1Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWeb1Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

////////////////////////////////IndexController////////////////////

```
package com.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    String index(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

////////////////////////PersonController///////////////////

```
package com.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;


import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


import com.model.Person;
import com.service.PersonService;

@Controller
public class PersonController {
    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

     @Autowired
        public void setPersonService(PersonService personService) {
            this.personService = personService;
        }


        @RequestMapping(value = "/persons", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String list(Model model){
            model.addAttribute("persons", personService.listAllPersons());

            return "persons";
        }


        @RequestMapping("person/{id}")
        public String showPerson(@PathVariable Integer id, Model model){
            model.addAttribute("person", personService.getPersonById(id));
            return "personshow";
        }


        @RequestMapping("person/edit/{id}")
        public String edit(@PathVariable Integer id, Model model){
            model.addAttribute("person", personService.getPersonById(id));
            return "personform";
        }


        @RequestMapping("person/new")
        public String newPerson(Model model){
            model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
            return "personform";
        }


        @RequestMapping(value = "person", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String saveProduct(Person person){
            personService.savePerson(person);
            return "redirect:/person/" + person.getId();
        }


        @RequestMapping("person/delete/{id}")
        public String delete(@PathVariable Integer id){
            personService.deletePerson(id);
            /*return "redirect:/products";*/
            return "personform";

        }


}
```

/////////////////////////////////Person//////////////////////////

```
package com.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Person {
     @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer id;
        private String name;
        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

}
```

/////////////////////////////PersonDetail/////////////////////////////

```
package com.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;


@Entity
@Table(name = "PersonDetail", catalog = "myschema")
public class PersonDetail {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String address;
    private Integer age;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Person person;

    public PersonDetail(){}

    public PersonDetail(Integer id,String address,Integer age)
    {
        this.id=id;
        this.address=address;
        this.age=age;
    }

    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign")
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
            @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "address", nullable = false, length = 20)
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }


    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Column(name = "age", nullable = false)
    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }


    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }


}
```

/////////////////////////////PersonRepository//////////////////////////////

```
package com.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.model.Person;
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Integer>{
}
```

//////////////////////////PersonDetailRepository/////////////////////

```
package com.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.model.PersonDetail;

public interface PersonDetailRepository extends CrudRepository<PersonDetail, Integer>{

}
```

///////////////////////////////Service///////////////////////

```
package com.service;

import com.model.Person;



public interface PersonService {
     Iterable<Person> listAllPersons();

        Person getPersonById(Integer id);

        Person savePerson(Person person);

        void deletePerson(Integer id);
}
```

///////////////////////////////ServiceImpl/////////////////////

```
package com.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


import com.model.Person;
import com.repository.PersonRepository;
@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService{
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

      @Autowired
        public void setPersonRepository(PersonRepository personRepository) {
            this.personRepository = personRepository;
        }


    @Override
    public Iterable<Person> listAllPersons() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Person getPersonById(Integer id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return personRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Person savePerson(Person person) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return personRepository.save(person);
    }
     @Override
        public void deletePerson(Integer id) {
            personRepository.delete(id);

        }
}
```

////////////////////////index.jsp/////////////////////////////

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">

    <title>Spring Boot Example</title>
    <!-- <th:block th:include="fragments/headerinc :: head"></th:block> -->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div th:fragment="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" th:href="@{/}">Home</a>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#" th:href="@{/persons}">Persons</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" th:href="@{/person/new}">Create Person</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div></nav></div>
<!-- <div class="container"> -->
   <!--  <th:block th:include="fragments/header :: header"></th:block> -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

/////////////////////////personform.jsp///////////////////////////

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">

    <title>Spring Boot Example</title>

     <th:block th:include="fragments/headerinc :: head"></th:block> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <th:block th:include="fragments/header :: header"></th:block> 

    <h2>Person Details</h2>
    <div>
        <form class="form-horizontal" th:object="${person}" th:action="@{/person}" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Person Id:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{id}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{name}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{address}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Age:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{age}"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

/////////////////////////persons//////////////////////

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">

    <title>Spring Boot Example</title>

   <th:block th:include="fragments/headerinc :: head"></th:block> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <!--/*/ <th:block th:include="fragments/header :: header"></th:block> /*/-->
    <div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(persons)}">
        <h2>Person List</h2>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Person Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Address</th>

                <th>View</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each="person : ${persons}">
                <td th:text="${person.id}"><a href="/person/${id}">Id</a></td>
                <td th:text="${person.id}">Person Id</td>
                <td th:text="${person.name}">description</td>
                <td th:text="${person.personDetail.address}">Address</td>
                <td th:text="${person.personDetail.age}">Age</td>
                <!--   <td th:text="${product.price}">price</td> -->
                <td><a th:href="${ '/person/' + person.id}">View</a></td>
                <td><a th:href="${'/person/edit/' + person.id}">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a th:href="${'/person/delete/' + person.id}">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

//////////////////////////personshow/////////////////////////////

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">

    <title>Person Details</title>

    <th:block th:include="fragments/headerinc :: head"></th:block> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <!--/*/ <th:block th:include="fragments/header :: header"></th:block> /*/-->

    <h2>Person Details</h2>
        <div>
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Person Id:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <p class="form-control-static" th:text="${person.id}">Person Id</p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <p class="form-control-static" th:text="${person.name}">name</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <p class="form-control-static" th:text="${person.personDetail.address}">address</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <p class="form-control-static" th:text="${person.personDetail.address}">age</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please show your code. Just google spring-data-jpa and hibernate and you will find thousand of explanations

Comment: there are thousands of examples, as you said, but none of them implements any kind of mappings. They are implementing the CRUD operations on single tables.

Comment: Yes. I will show my code.

Comment: I have updated my code. I have,here, a single table 'Person' on which I am perfforming CRUD operations. Now, I want to perform these operations on two tables mapped with each other using one-to-one mapping

Comment: can you show your other entity which should have the `onToOne` mapping with `person`?

Comment: I have not tried it yet. If I implement the one to one mapping, which other files do I need? I know, that I need another model (say, student.java) , another repository, its implementation in a service. Now, if I persorm CRUD operations, which table do I apply them on the original one, or the new one?

Comment: Do you have some kind of a demo or a working example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For example you have an entity `Person` and `PersonDetail` which will have an `@OneToOne` mapping. This means one Person has one PersonDetail. In the `Person` entity you have to set the mapping to `PersonDetail`.

I really suggest that you read the docs of hibernate and spring-data. And also the java-docs of the mappings. You will only understand how everything work together by learning the stuff step by step.

I provide you a little working example. Get your application working build on this example of code.

Person Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String firstName;
private String lastName;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private PersonDetail personDetail;

//getter setter

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
            ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
            ", personDetail=" + personDetail +
            '}';
}
}
```

PersonDetail Entity:

```
@Entity
public class PersonDetail {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String street;
private Integer postalCode;

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Person person;

//getter setter

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "PersonDetail{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", street='" + street + '\'' +
            ", postalCode=" + postalCode +
            '}';
}
}
```

Repositories:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
}
```

---

```
public interface PersonDetailRepository extends CrudRepository<PersonDetail, Long> {
}
```

Application Start class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApplication .class, args);
    }

    @Component
    class Dummy implements CommandLineRunner{

        @Autowired
        PersonRepository repo;

        @Override
        public void run(String... string) throws Exception {

            Person person = new Person();
            person.setFirstName("firstname");
            person.setLastName("lastname");
            PersonDetail personDetail = new PersonDetail();
            personDetail.setStreet("Street");
            person.setPersonDetail(personDetail);

            repo.save(person);

            repo.findAll().forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.toString()));

        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Person{id=1, firstName='firstname', lastName='lastname', personDetail=PersonDetail{id=1, street='Street', postalCode=null}}
```

Comment: thanks a lot Patrick. I have updated my question with my templates. What changes do I make in these templates, if I am performing crud operations on two tables?

Comment: I have updated my question with my code for the addtitonal PersonDetail model class and its repository. I am now trying the jsp part. Will I need join queries for fetching data from these two mapped tables?

Comment: @AP No, your entities are already mapped with `@OneToOne` annotation. Just fetch one `Person` and the `PersonDetail` is fetched, too. In the jsp you would do `person.personDetail.street` for example. Use a debugger to see whats happening when you execute functions to get your entity

Comment: ok. Corresponding to this, what changes will be there in my jsps? or should new jsps be created?

Comment: since I am performing the fetching operation, I want to display the data from both the tables on a single page, say, the persons.jsp

Comment: If you set `Person` to a `modelAttribute` it will be useable in the view. And because `Person` and `PersonDetail` are mapped, `PersonDetail` is also visible. So just use the object in the view. `person.personDetail.street`

Comment: and what about the controller? What changes will come there?

Comment: no changes. you can just use it like it is. By the way your Person entity does not have the oneToOne mapping with personDetail. Dont know if you want that. But anyway, I suggest you to learn more about MVC and Spring-Data/Hibernate. Because I think you dont really understand the basics how it works together.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122963/discussion-between-a-p-and-patrick).

Comment: I solved that mapping error. I had mentioned the name of the table as 'PersonDetail' , but its corresponding mapping was given like this : 'personDetail'.  
     
\

Comment: Now, I am getting a new error : Invalid property 'person' of bean class [com.model.Person]: Bean property 'person' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Comment: I have given the appropriate mapping in the models and the tamplates. Can somebody suggest a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

If You want **unidirectional** OneToOne mapping, here is how I made it.

I had a model like this: There is a request for some items, and there are people making offers. I wanted to know which offer is the chosen one (no pun intended ;) ). So, here are both classes:

Request.java

```
@Entity
public class Request {
    // id and other columns...

    @JoinColumn(name = "chosen_offer")
    @OneToOne
    private Offer chosenOffer = null;

    // constructors, getters, setters, etc.
}
```

Offer.java

```
@Entity
public class Offer {
    // id and other columns...

    // nothing special here

    // constructors, getters, setters, etc.
}
```

Here is how my table of SupplyRequests looked like (using MySQL WorkBench):

[requests MySQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0ZaS.png)